# Collaborative DrawBoard Java Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, draw, collaborative

I am trying to make a Drawing board game, basically like draw my thing but fully user controlled where a group of friends can just pick and draw. The idea is someone submits what they are drawing, and then they draw it; first one to guess the drawing wins. It will be very trust based, and it is casual.

I have the paint working, but I have no clue how I can setup a client and server to make a collaborative drawboard, I would also like to make the server multithreaded so many clients can join.

Please help me!

Here is the pastebin to my Paint class: http://pastebin.com/hHK9WJz2

Ps: I tried to do something with sockets and they are in there.

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Comment: I don't know how I could send my drawings inbetween client and server in real time